# Android SDK After Release apk Some Buttons does not show image

Tags: android, performance

IN My Project there are several Activities and Every Activity has an ImageViewer and many Buttons. Every Button show a different image on click. 
Inspect Code does not show any error.
Application runs fine when testing on Emulator and also fine in Debug Mode.
However when I release the Project and Install it on my android Phone some Button do not work.

Comment: have you enabled proguard on the release version?. Sometimes it can cause some problems

Comment: I Have enabled proguard on the release version but same problem face.

Comment: Actually some Buttons show Blank ImageViewer where Large Image  attached.